# How do I eliminate duplicate user accounts?

Tags: user-accounts

I have a user who is listed only once in our AD, only comes up once in the user selection search, however she is listed twice when looking at a user field within a the datasheet view.

Is there any way to purge this duplicate?  They are distinctly different in the eyes of SharePoint as can be seen by the lookup ID in the second part of the image below.

We are using claims based auth.

Updates: It is 2010, and I am 100% positive there is only 1 AD account for this person.

Updates 2: I just checked and sure enough an old, non-claims account was listed for her:
[image]

I guess it's a matter of deleting her old account from the site collection?

[image]

Comment: Please explicitly specify whicih version of SharePoint you are using.

Comment: @ukhardy looks like 2010 to me. Are you sure this person really doesn't have two accounts in AD? If not, maybe you could delete the user from the site collection..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This user probably HAD two accounts in AD, and one of the accounts that doesn't exist anymore is still assigned to the list that you are opening in datasheet view. Please check if there is any permission assignment to this user, remove all their assignments and add them again only for the valid account.

You can also try stsadm -o migrateuser command and provide same login for old and new parameter, this should refresh the user details in your applications.

Comment: This is actually what I think the issue is.  I'm going to try and will mark if correct.

Answer (score 7):

If the user had two accounts, you should check which account the user should be using and then use Move-SPUser PowerShell command for SharePoint 2010 to migrate the old user to the new one.

```
Move-SPUser –Identity "DOMAIN\JaneDoe" –NewAlias "Domain\JaneSmith"
```

More information on the PowerShell command is available here:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607729.aspx

Comment: What happens if the correct account already exists?  This bit is concerning ...  " If an entry for the new login name already exists, the entry is marked for deletion to make way for the migration."